# lose original file date while coping to samba share

Tags: samba, dolphin

I have an issue while copying files to a `samba` share.
The situation is a little bit strange because Ubuntu's `Files` application works properly but if I copy a file with `Krusader` and `Dolphin` I lose the original file date. I really want to use Krusader's `Synchronize Folder` tool but it does not work properly because of this issue.

**Samba server: Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon**

```
$ sudo smbstatus

Samba version 4.11.6-Ubuntu
PID     Username     Group        Machine                                   Protocol Version  Encryption           Signing              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
343250  nobody       nogroup      hp (ipv4:10.42.0.213:53576)               SMB3_11           -                    -                    
344078  myuser       myuser       10.42.0.213 (ipv4:10.42.0.213:47010)      SMB3_11           -                    partial(AES-128-CMAC)
343496  myuser       myuser       10.42.0.213 (ipv4:10.42.0.213:46946)      SMB3_11           -                    partial(AES-128-CMAC)
343429  myuser       myuser       10.42.0.213 (ipv4:10.42.0.213:46868)      SMB3_11           -                    partial(AES-128-CMAC)

Service      pid     Machine       Connected at                     Encryption   Signing     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
backup       343429  10.42.0.213   Mon Oct 26 10:14:03 PM 2020 CET  -            -           
backup       344078  10.42.0.213   Mon Oct 26 10:29:36 PM 2020 CET  -            -           
IPC$         343250  hp            Mon Oct 26 10:08:36 PM 2020 CET  -            -           
backup       343496  10.42.0.213   Mon Oct 26 10:16:34 PM 2020 CET  -            -
```

Configuration what I changed/added:

```
[global]
   interfaces = wlp1s0
   bind interfaces only = yes

   min protocol = SMB2
   client min protocol = SMB2
   client max protocol = SMB3

[backup]
    path = /home/abc/Backup
    writeable = yes
    guest ok = no
```

**Samba Client: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**

- The original file locates here, file date: 30/Mar/2015
- I opened Krusader, Dolphin, and Ubuntu's internal file browser the Files (you can see these three connections above)

Result of copy the same file from the client to the server:

- Files copy: date is okay
- Dolphin: not ok, date on the server is the date of the copy (now)
- Krusader: not ok, date on the server is the date of the copy (now)

So only the `Files` application copy the file correctly.

```
$ smbclient -L remotemachine
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter WORKGROUP\abc's password:

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    backup          Disk      
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (remotemachine server (Samba, Ubuntu))
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.
protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE
Failed to connect with SMB1 -- no workgroup available
```

I think that the server configuration is correct because it works properly with `Files`.

Do you have any idea what I need to check on my client machine?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is an old known and fixed bug in kio-extras: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=356651